# How to parse HTMLDivElement into template literals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, template-literals

I want to parse HTML elements into JS template literals

```
  var featurePosts = $('.featured-posts > div'), html

  switch (featurePosts.length) {
    case 1:
      html = `<div class="feature${featurePosts.length}">${featurePosts[0]}</div>`
      break;
    case 2:
      html = `<div class="feature${featurePosts.length}">${featurePosts[0]}${featurePosts[1]}</div>`
      break;
    case 3:
      html = '<div class="feature${featurePosts.length}">'+
          '<div class="grid grid-one">'+featurePosts[0]+'</div>'+
          '<div class="grid grid-two">${featurePosts[1]}${featurePosts[2]}</div>'+
        '</div>'
      break;
    case 4:
    case 5:
      html = `<div class="feature${featurePosts.length}">
          <div class="grid grid-one">${featurePosts[0]}</div>
          <div class="grid grid-two">${featurePosts[1]}${featurePosts[2]}</div>
          <div class="grid grid-three">
            ${featurePosts[3]}${featurePosts[4]}
          </div>
        </div>`
      break;
  }
  
  $('.featured-posts').html(html)
```

and it returns something like `[object HTMLDivElement]` Please anybody help me. Thanks

Comment: Use `outerHTML` i.e : `${featurePosts[0].outerHTML}` same for all..

Comment: Try ` $('.featured-posts').html($.parseHTML(html))`.

Comment: Hi @Swati it solves my problem, i am new here and i don't know much about it,  Please put your commnet as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use String() metod

```
 let html = String()
              +'<div>exemple</div>';
```

Comment: Have you have the same problem using this? Or something other?

Comment: Additional hint In case 3 you didn't use ``. In case 4 you didnt used + after each line.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time resolving it, we just need to use `outerHTML` in order to parse the HTML element.

like

```
${featurePosts[0].outerHTML}
```